# Stripe Plan switching error with cancel_at_period_end parameter

Tags: stripe-payments

The [official Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrading-downgrading) on their website has some examples in various different languages to switch subscription plans for a customer. This is the code snippet they provide:

```
Subscription subscription = Subscription.retrieve("sub_49ty4767H20z6a");

Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<>();
item.put("cancel_at_period_end", false);
item.put("id", subscription.getSubscriptionItems().getData().get(0).getId());
item.put("plan", "plan_CBb6IXqvTLXp3f");

Map<String, Object> items = new HashMap<>();
items.put("0", item);

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("items", items);

subscription.update(params);
```

I've used the exact code given in the example to switch from one plan to another for a customer, but I get the following error:

> com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: Received unknown parameter: items[0][cancel_at_period_end]; code: parameter_unknown;

I'm working with Java, but it doesn't matter what language because all the examples have that same `cancel_at_period_end` parameter in the subscription item. [According to the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#update_subscription_item), there is no `cancel_at_period_end` parameter for subscription items.

I've tried removing that parameter from the example, and the plan switching works correctly. Is this a mistake in the docs, or am I missing something important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is incorrect as `cancel_at_period_end` is a top-level parameter.

The code should be:

```
Subscription subscription = Subscription.retrieve("sub_49ty4767H20z6a");

Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<>();
item.put("id", subscription.getSubscriptionItems().getData().get(0).getId());
item.put("plan", "plan_CBb6IXqvTLXp3f");

Map<String, Object> items = new HashMap<>();
items.put("0", item);

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("items", items);
params.put("cancel_at_period_end", false);

subscription.update(params);
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but personally I'd remove the `cancel_at_period_end` parameter from the example entirely. For my use case, if a customer has switched off subscription auto-renewal, I don't want to assume that they want it switched back on just because they've made a change to their account that upgrades their plan. If they want to turn auto-renewal back on, they'll know what to do. The parameter is superfluous to the example, the code in particular. A note about it in the page text would be better, in my opinion.

Comment: I would disagree. Most people that decide to cancel their plan at the end of the period and later come back to change plans would likely want to have it start renewing after all.